# Trouble evaluating combinations from combn using purrr

Tags: r, purrr

I am trying to use combn to divide a group of n = 20 different units into 3 groups of unequal size -- 4, 6 and 10.  Then I am trying to validate for values that must be together within a group -- if one element from the pair exists in the group then the other should also be in the group.  If one is not in the group then neither should be in the group.  In this fashion, I'd like to evaluate the groups in order to find all possible valid solutions where the rules are true.

```r
x <- letters[1:20]

same_group <- list(
  c("a", "c"),
  c("d", "f"),
  c("b", "k", "r")
)

combinations_list <- combn(x, 4, simplify = F)

validate_combinations <- function(x) all(c("a", "c") %in% x) | !any(c("a", "c") %in% x)

valid_combinations <- keep(combinations_list, validate_combinations)
```

In this way I'd like to combine -> reduce each group until I have a list of all valid combinations.  I'm not sure how to combine combinations_list, validate_combinations, and the same_group to check all same_group "rules" against the combinations in the table.  The furthest I can get is to check against one combination c("a", "c"), which when run against keep(combinations_list, validate_combinations) is indeed giving me the output I want.

I think once I can do this, I can then use the unpicked values in another combn function for the group of 6 and the group of 10.

Comment: Where do you use `same_group`

Comment: Yes, that is my question exactly.  It should go somewhere into the validate_combination function instead of the hardcoded c("a", "c") which are the first elements of that list, but I have not been able to figure out that level of abstraction.

Comment: I would change the function from function(x, y) all (y %in% x)...` and use `map` to loop over the combinations_list and apply the function with y

Comment: Try `validate_combinations <- function(vec, x) all(vec %in% x) | !any(vec %in% x);
out <- map(same_group, ~ keep(combinations_list, validate_combinations, vec = .x))`

Answer (score 0):

We can change the function to accept variable group

```
validate_combinations <- function(x, group) all(group %in% x) | !any(group %in% x)
```

then for each `group` subset the `combinations_list` which satisfy `validate_combinations`

```
lapply(same_group, function(x)  combinations_list[
       sapply(combinations_list, function(y) validate_combinations(y, x))])


#[[1]]
#[[1]][[1]]
#[1] "a" "b" "c" "d"

#[[1]][[2]]
#[1] "a" "b" "c" "e"

#[[1]][[3]]
#[1] "a" "b" "c" "f"

#[[1]][[4]]
#[1] "a" "b" "c" "g"

#[[1]][[5]]
#[1] "a" "b" "c" "h"

#[[1]][[6]]
#[1] "a" "b" "c" "i"

#[[1]][[7]]
#[1] "a" "b" "c" "j"

#[[1]][[8]]
#[1] "a" "b" "c" "k"
#......
```